# how to fetch all records from order table in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

`$data` is an array which contain user post data for fetch record from orders table

```
$data=array('customer_id'=>$this->input->post('custId'),'paided'=>2);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->where($data);
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: its didn't return required data where i am wrong please suggest me

Comment: What is your require data and what wrong with your query???

Comment: my required data is in orders table where we pass customer id as custId and paided =2 , which records belongs to this condition they all are needed

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array(
    'customer_id'       =>      $this->input->post('custId')],
    'paided'            =>      2   
);

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->where($data);

$this->db->get();
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
public function function_name (){
 $data = array (
    'customer_id' => $this->input->post('custId'),
    'paided'      => 2
 );

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('ordere');
 $this->db->where($data);

 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have done all good just need to put result() if you get multiple row or row() if you get one row

```
$data=array('customer_id'=>$this->input->post('custId'),'paided'=>2);
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->where($data);
$result= $this->db->get()->result(); //added result()
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the plus of using framework, you don't need to write that much of code,

```
$where = array('customer_id' => $this->input->post('custId'),'paided'=>2)

$result = $this->db->get_where('orders', $where);
```

and for fetching them, use `$result->row()` for single record retrieval.

If you want all records, use `$result->result()`

Here is [documentation link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html), if you want to learn more.

Comment: i need  whole recordsin orders table  where 'customer_id'=$this->input->post('custId');  and ' paided '=2

Answer (score 0):

as simple use

```
$custId = $_post['custId'];

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id= '$custId'  AND paided='2'");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;//result will be array
```

Answer (score 0):

What You should need to be Correct And Why

```
$data=array('customer_id'=>$this->input->post('custId'),'paided'=>2);
$this->db->select('*'); // by defaul select all so no need to pass *
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->where($data);
$this->db->get(); // this will not return data this is just return object
```

So Your Code Should be

```
$data=array('customer_id'=>$this->input->post('custId'),'paided'=>2);
$this->db->select(); // by defaul select all so no need to pass *
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->where($data);

$query = $this->db->get();
$data = $query->result_array();
// or You can 
 $data= $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

> here `result_array()` return pure array where you can also use `result()`
>   this will return array of object